# Session on Flask server with Python requests package not working

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I've written Flask server with flask_login. To login user, I use `login_user(user)`, and I have one page of my site protected with `@login_required`. As a client, I use Python requests package, that's the code:

```
import requests
sess = requests.session()
sess.post("http://page.on/my/site", data={"login" : "login", "password" : "password"})
```

Everything is OK with this authentication, but then I try to access the secured page:

```
r = sess.get("http://secure.page/on/the/site")
```

And this requests receives `Unauthorized`. 
That's cookies set after authentication (for now I have my server on localhost):

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie session=.eJwdzjkSwjAMAMC_uE4h2dbhfCZjHR5oE1Ix_B2Gbst9l2OdeT3K_jrv3MrxjLKX5tqBGbq7MfmPiYi8aA7RAG8haZJoDZ0HrlSG6Oa1-yCqsaJNJlSVAQToNXsAt8UiFQBIbIa3bmYiarYyiEaNsUJjmlLZyn3l-c_Uzxf_2C6a.Cnf0yA.xIUSIFgcvjqwszrbwCA_D2Rqa5k for localhost.local/>]>
```

BTW, I also use this:

```
login_manager.session_protection = "strong"
```

How to fix this authentication problems?

UPD:

That's server login code:

```
@api.route("/login/", methods=["POST"])
def handle_login_request():
    login, password = str(request.form['login']).lower(), str(request.form['password'])
    # Get and check user here
    login_user(user)
    # update user and get user_data
    return jsonify(user_data)
```

Secured route:

```
@api.route("/users_of_group/")
@login_required
def get_user_of_users_group():
    # code here never executes because of @login_required
```

`api` is the name of flask Blueprint

UPD2:

That's content of page returned by `sess.get`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
 <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
 <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
 <p>The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested.  You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.</p>
```

UPD3:
I tried to use this:

```
r = sess.get("http://secure.page/on/the/site", auth=("login", "password"))
```

On the server I can see, that at first user is successfully logged in, but then the server throws 401 anyway.

```
import requests
sess = requests.session()
login = sess.post("http://page.on/my/site", data={"login" : "login", "password" : "password"})
r = sess.get("http://secure.page/on/the/site", cookies=login.cookies)
```

Also logins user and then throws 401.

UPD4:

Problem appears to be in login_user function, it doesn't change `is_authenticated` to `True`. I use SQLAlchemy and this is my user class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Many required for my app fields
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_authenticated = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_anonymous = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    is_online = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    # Init function 

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.user_id)
```

And `user_loader`:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print(user_id, type(user_id))
    user = User.query.filter_by(user_id=int(user_id)).first()
    print(user.login, user.is_authenticated)
    return user
```

Id is printed correctly, its type is `str`, query works just fine, but I still get `Unauthenticated` error, and in the last `print` `user.is_authenticated` is False.

UPD5:

Actually, printing `user.is_authenticated` just after `login_user` also shows False, even though I called `session.commit()` after `login_user`.

Comment: According to the docs, _[w]hen session protection is active, each request, it generates an identifier for the user’s computer (basically, a secure hash of the IP address and user agent)._ So it doesn't look like that's an issue at all. Can you post a full [mcve]?

Comment: @WayneWerner, see my updated answer

Comment: You're missing the user loader and your user class from your question, but it's likely that my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to exhibit the behavior that you explain:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_user, login_required, \
                        current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'This is totally a secret'
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.session_protection = 'strong'


class User(UserMixin):
    id = 42

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        print('{!r}'.format(self.id))
        return self.id == 42


@login_manager.user_loader
def get_user(id):
    user = User()
    user.id = id
    return user


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User()
        user.id = request.form.get('id', 42)
        login_user(user)
    else:
        user = current_user
    return 'Okay, logged in with id {}'.format(user.id)


@app.route('/')
@login_required
def main():
    return 'Hey cool - your id {}'.format(current_user.id)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

What to note here is that the ID is `'42'`, not `42`. Apparently decoding the id from the session is not clever enough to know that your ID is anything but a string. By changing my function to `return str(self.id) == '42'`, it works. I suspect that you have something similar setup in your user loader or your user class.

As I suspected - your user model is producing an incorrect `is_authenticated`. Of course it's highly likely that it's doing *exactly* what you tell it to. You'll simply have to fix the authenticated bit. Do note that if you return `None` from your user loader that it will use an anonymous user - you could hard-code `True` in your `is_authenticated` method, unless perhaps you're trying to log out the user across sessions.

Comment: `Flask-Login` *requires* your user ID to be a text type (`unicode` in 2.7 and `str` in 3.x). See the [`get_id`](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) documentation. Well, I guess strictly speaking, you could override `get_id` to do the conversion, but `get_id` has to return a text type.

Comment: Useful to know - I suspect the `UserMixin` does that behind the scenes for `get_id`.

Comment: @WayneWerner, I've just tried this and added some debug prints, and the problem is quite different - see my updated answer

Comment: Actually it's exactly this problem - your `is_authenticated` value is returning False. I'll add some details to my answer

Comment: I've updated my answer a bit - if you want something specific you're going to have to provide the rest of your login method.